# how do i call SetRootViewController from a view controller using swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I am trying to use setRootViewController in swift from a UIViewController not from app delegate.

I found some questions on stack overflow but everywhere they have explained to do it from app delegate. However, I want to do it from a UIViewController and set UITabBarController as a rootViewController

This is how i did it in objective c

```
UITabBarController *main = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:main];
```

I would like to do the same in swift. Is there any way to do it in swift or do i need to use segue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do that using the following line of code:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController = mainViewController
```

Comment: Thanks man, its seems to work. But can you please explain why you used double question marks after window. "??" ? thanks

Comment: If you look at the `window` declaration in the `UIApplication` protocol, you see that it is declared as `optional`: `optional var window: UIWindow? { get set }`, which means the adopter of this protocol is not required to implement that property. The first `?` is for the property being declared as optional, the 2nd for the property itself being an optional - a little confusing, maybe this can clarify: [Optional Protocol Requirements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_415)